# Azure URL encoding in nopcommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, nopcommerce

We have nopcommerce solution hosted on AZURE.

Nop have 3 languages LV, EN, and RU, with URL SEO frendly enabled.
All URL are encoded based on language for example:

```
xhttp://xcom.lv/ru/Ноутбуки
xhttp://xcom.lv/ru/notebooks
```

When we switch language from RU to EN, everything is ok.
When we switch from EN to RU we get url like this:

[image: Wrong URL]

On local IIS under VS everything is ok. On shared hostings with IIS also is ok.

What is wrong?